# How get the url parameters with variable from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code...like this...

```
$version = 2.0;
$customerid = 234;
$data = trim($row['signform']);  // this url string in mysql
echo $data;


//The browser result is
'version='.$version.'&customerid='.$customerid
```

I can't get the result like

```
version=2.0&customerid=234
```

But if I set

```
$version = 2.0;
$customerid = 234;
$data = 'version='.$version.'&customerid='.$customerid;
echo $data;
```

I got it!

Now, I need to load the parameter string contain $variable, which value set before, then browser show the string like

```
version=2.0&customerid=234
```

Comment: You need to `eval` the code. But please don’t. Also this looks like the XY problem. What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: really unclear what you are asking

Comment: Wait a second... first of all, have you even tried doing anything? Secondly, if you have, is your problem related to `2.0` showing up as `2`? Because if that’s the case, you should be using Strings instead, since 2.0 (float) is equivalent to 2 (integer). Thirdly, be clear with your question and don’t expect people to code for you! Instead of asking how to do something (StackOverflow is not a tutorial site), ask why your code isn’t working the way you expected. Thank you!

Comment: your edit makes less snse

Answer (score 0):

```
$version = 2.0;
$customerid = 234;
$total_fee=100;
$data = trim($row['signform']);
$cc = eval("echo $data;");
echo $cc;
```

Resoved!

Comment: dont ever use eval

Comment: From the PHP Manual: "The eval() language construct is _very dangerous_ because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. _Its use thus is discouraged_. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention _not to pass any user provided data_ into it without properly validating it beforehand.". [Read more in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).